# how to choose total of 3 obs per branch?

Tags: sql, sas, partition, proc

I wish to choose only 3 OBS per branch, where I need to answer these rules:

1. if there are only 2 accounts in the branch - bring the 2 highest incomes from the first branch and 1 from the second account
2. if there are 3 accounts in the branch - bring 1 observation per account, which are the highest ones.
3. if there are 4 or more accounts per branch - bring 1 observation per account, , which are the highest ones - **whilst not repeating the same account twice**

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  How do you define "first" account and "second" account.  Unlike SAS datasets, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . The `row_id` column seems to be ordering the incomes within an account.  So, you should be able to use `proc sql`, although it is a little messy:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select crm_branch_id, count(distinct account_id) as cnt
      from t
      group by crm_branch_id
     ) b
     on b.crm_branch_id = t.crm_branch_id
where (cnt = 1 and t.row_id <= 3) or
      (cnt = 2 and t.row_id = 1 or
       cnt = 2 and t.row_id = 2 and
       t.income = (select max(t2.income)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.crm_branch_id = t.crm_branch_id and
                       t2.row_id = 2
                )
      ) or
      (cnt = 3 and row_id = 1) or
      (cnt > 3 and row_id = 1 and
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.crm_branch_id = t.crm_branch_id and
              t2.row_id = 1 and
              t2.income >= t.income
       ) <= 3
      );
```

The arcane logic in the `where` clause is to handle the different numbers of accounts:

- If there is one account, take the top three rows.
- If there are two accounts, take the two rows with `row_id = 1` and then the top row where `row_id = 2`.
- If there are three accounts, take the rows with `row_id = 1`.
- If there are four or more accounts, only consider rows where `row_id = 1`.  Then take the top three of those based on income.

Answer (score 0):

DOW processing can perform the complexion selection.

- First loop, count number of `account`s in `branch`
- Second loop, output top `income`s according to rules

  - Requires data be pre order in the following manner

    - contiguous in `branch` and `account`
    - descending `income`
    - ascending `seq_act`

Example:

```
data have;
input income account_id branch_id seq_act;
datalines;
 1224932 123 358 1
  700400 123 358 2
  646730 123 358 3
  644677 123 358 4
    2017 123 358 5
11338320 567 358 1
 3806060 567 358 2
 3642089 567 358 3
 1403174 567 358 4
  400530 567 358 5
;

/* presume data is
 * - contiguous by branch and account
 * - descending income
 * - ascending seq_act
 */

data want(drop=i n);
  * count number of accounts in branch;
  do until (last.branch_id);
    set have;
    by branch_id account_id notsorted descending income /*ascending*/ seq_act;

    n + first.account_id;
  end;

  do until (last.branch_id);

    set have;
    by branch_id account_id notsorted;

    i + first.account_id;

    select (n);
      when (1) if seq_act <= 3 then output;   /* first 3 when 1 account */
      when (2) if seq_act <= 3-i then output; /* first 2 then first 1 when 2 accounts */
      otherwise if seq_act = 1 then output;   /* first 1 from each account */
    end;
  end;

  i = 0;
  n = 0;
run;
```

Output

[image]